# LINQ - filtering and updating property on an IEnumerable collection

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to understand how the concatenation of `.Except` and `.ForEach` works in a LINQ expression if I am working with references in ForEach.

I have an IEnumaerable collection of objects and my requirement is to update a property on a subset of objects from the original collection. I tried using except and foreach in an expression and the property is not updated.

```
private Size[] FilterCollection()
{    
   var collection1 = { {
      "Bytes": 56,
      "Name": "low",
      "Code": "XS"
    },
    {
      "Bytes": 123,
      "Name": "medium",
      "Code": "M"
    },
    {
      "Bytes": 8888,
      "Name": "large",
      "Code": "M"
    }
  };

  var collection2 = { {
      "Bytes": 56,
      "Name": "low",
      "Code": "XS"
    },
    {
      "Bytes": 8888,
      "Name": "large",
      "Code": "M"
    }
  };                     

 collection1= collection1.ToArray();
 collection1.Except(collection2, new CustomComparer()).ForEach(x=> x.Code= null);
 return collection1;
}

 private class CustomComparer: IEqualityComparer<Size>
    {
        public bool Equals(Size x, Size y)
        {
            return x.Name == y.Name;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Size obj)
        {
            return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
{ 
    {
      "Bytes": 56,
      "Name": "low",
      "Code": "XS"
    },
    {
      "Bytes": 123,
      "Name": "medium",
      "Code": null
    },
    {
      "Bytes": 8888,
      "Name": "large",
      "Code": "M"
    }
}
```

But when I concatenate .ToArray() to the rest of the expression, the 'Code' property is not updated

```
collection1.ToArray().Except(collection2, new CustomComparer()).ForEach(x=> x.Code= null);
return collection1;
```

Output:

```
{ 
    {
      "Bytes": 56,
      "Name": "low",
      "Code": "XS"
    },
    {
      "Bytes": 123,
      "Name": "medium",
      "Code": "M"
    },
    {
      "Bytes": 8888,
      "Name": "large",
      "Code": "M"
    }
}
```

Can somebody explain what the difference between these 2 expressions is?

Comment: Copy in the code for your CustomComparer class.  That should help.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid C# code. Are you trying to show initialization and output in a special way or something, because you're confusing me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Calling `ToArray()` creates a new array with the results of the linq query. Therefore, it is essentially creating a copy of your enumerable results(check out here for an explanation of [deferred execution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/10/linq-and-deferred-execution/)).  In your first example, you are assigned the newly created array into your `collection1` variable and then calling `Except` and `Foreach` on the new array.  In your second example, you are creating the new array and calling the `Except` and `Foreach` methods on it, but you are not capturing the array in a variable.  instead you are returning the original enumerable.

Check this link out for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: True, calling ToArray() creates a new collection, but with the same object references, providing Size is a class, not a struct. So changing a property in the new array will change it in the old collection.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Size` class overrides `Equals()`, then you can use the `Except<T>()`method without the IEqualityComparator. To use the `Except<>(second, comparor)` method you used, it requires you to build your own custom comparator class.

Option 1:

```
public class Size
{
    //Properties and stuff...

    public override Equals(object obj)
    {
        Size other = obj as Size;
        if (other != null)
            return other.Name == this.Name && other.Bytes == this.Bytes;
        return false;
    }
}
```

in your method:

```
collection1.Except(collection2).ForEach(x => x.Code = null);
```

Option 2:

```
public class MyComparator : IEqualityComparer<Size>
{
    public bool Equals(Size x, Size y)
    {
        return x.Name == y.Name && x.Bytes == y.Bytes;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Size obj)
    {
        return obj.Bytes;
    }
}
```

in your method:

```
collection1.Except(collection2, new MyComparator()).ForEach(x => x.Code = null);
```